# Are There Other Use Cases For F# Type Providers?

Tags: f#

So I think I know the main use case for F# 3.0's Type Providers, i. e. better Intellisense when working with data stores that use them.  Are there other use cases for Type Providers or is that pretty much it?

Comment: As written, this is a list-style question which would be off-topic.  Would you provide some more details around your question so we can provide a better answer for you?

Comment: @GlenH7 Fair criticism but I couldn't think of any other way to phrase this.  Close it if you want; I'll ask on the F# mailing lists.  Just thought others might want to know this as well.

Comment: I suspect that the list of possible uses is constrained enough that the question is answerable.  If the idea of a laundry list bothers you, specify a category of uses in your answer.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if phrased as "What is *the* main usecase for F# 3.0's Type Providers, aside from better Intellisense" or maybe "Aside from aiding the IDE, what is the main purpose in adding Type Providers to F# 3.0"? Of course, I don't actually work with F# so it's also possible these variations of the question don't even make sense. ;)

Comment: They're used primarily for accessing diverse data sources, such as databases and web services.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156509.aspx

Comment: @RobertHarvey You should post that as an answer--I'd up vote that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll find that  there is really only 1 use case for F# Type Providers - that is, getting strongly typed data from data sources.

What I think you might be asking is what good is getting that kind of type information? Well, as you mentioned, it allows you to use intellisense better, but I think that's actually a side effect or more of a happy coincidence.

I think you'll find that the benefits of having strongly typed data available are inline with the benefits of having a strongly typed language to begin with.

Interestingly, if you take a look at [the page](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=173076) that has (what I believe to be) the original spec/proposal/design document for type providers, you'll find:

> Providing strongly typed access to these sources is **a key consideration for strongly-typed programming languages**, to insure low impedance mismatch in information access. At this scale, *[current methods]* are manual, clumsy, and do not handle the internet-scale information sources...

(emphasis and edits mine)

Answer (score 1):

There are F# Type Providers for things other than what is traditionally thought of as data.

One example is the [FunScript](http://funscript.info/) type provider:

> FunScript is a lightweight F# library that lets you rapidly develop
>   single-page applications. You can connect to external data sources and
>   call REST APIs with intellisense, produce dashboards using JavaScript
>   visualization libraries and write asynchronous computations easily
>   without explicit callbacks.

Another one is the [F# R type provider](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider):

> An F# type provider for interoperating with R.

So you can see that type providers can be used to provide interoperability to other programming languages (JavaScript and R shown here).